# AWS Object Tagging using x-amz-tagging request header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading the contents of a file to s3 using the `Put Object` endpoint and attempting to use the `x-amz-tagging` request header.

See documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html.

As in example 6 in the link above:

> Example 6: Upload an Object and Specify Tags
>
> In this upload object request, you specify the optional x-amz-taggging
>   header to add tags to the object.
>
> Copy PUT /example-object HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com    Accept: */*
>   Authorization:authorization string    Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 21:58:13
>   GMT    x-amz-tagging: tag1=value1&tag2=value2
>
> [... bytes of object data]

I generate a base string like so used to generate the authorization string:

```
String baseString = "PUT\n\ntext/plain\n" 
    + currentDate + "\n" 
    + "x-amz-tagging:tag1=value1&tag2=value2" + "\n" 
    + "/" + LOG_BUCKET_NAME + THE_REST_OF_THE_URL;
```

Then build my request like so:

```
request.setRawHeader("Date", currentDate);
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);
request.setRawHeader("x-amz-tagging", "tag1=value&tag2=value2);
```

I get a forbidden error every time but adding **metadata** works perfectly:

Base string:

```
String baseString = "PUT\n\ntext/plain\n" 
    + currentDate + "\n" 
    + "x-amz-meta-reviewedby:my_email@domain.com" + "\n" 
    + "/" + LOG_BUCKET_NAME + THE_REST_OF_THE_URL;
```

And then:

```
request.setRawHeader("Date", currentDate);
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);
request.setRawHeader("X-Amz-Meta-ReviewedBy", "my_email@domain.com");
```

Is there perhaps additional user permissions required for adding tags?

Answer (score 4):

It was in fact a permissions issue. The fix involved enabling user permissions for Object Tagging.

Comment: Where do you change it?

Comment: It's changed on the S3 Bucket Policy.  If you're using CloudFormation, your template should include a AWS::S3::BucketPolicy definition that references the bucket in the Bucket property, the CloudFront Origin Access User as the Principal, and includes "s3:PutObjectTagging" in the Action.  If you're maintaining things via the AWS console, go to the S3 bucket, select the Permissions tab, and then click on "Bucket Policy".  From there you should be able to add s3:PutObjectTagging to your allowed actions.